# Understanding this palindrome code in C++

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this piece of code for finding out if something is a palindrome or not.

I was hoping someone could break it down for me and make it simple stupid.

I included the full code but I think the part that's baffling me, is this line

```cpp
for (int i = text.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reversed_text += text[i];
}
```

Thanks in advance!

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// Define is_palindrome() here:
bool is_palindrome(std::string text){
    std::string reversed_text = "";
   
    for (int i = text.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reversed_text += text[i];
    }
      
    if (reversed_text == text){
        return true;
    }
        return false;
    }
} 

int main() {
  
    std::cout << is_palindrome("madam") << "\n";
    std::cout << is_palindrome("ada") << "\n";
    std::cout << is_palindrome("lovelace") << "\n";
  
}
```

Comment: Try stepping through the code in your debugger and inspecting the values of `i` and `reversed_text` at each step.  That should make it pretty obvious.

Comment: A palindrom is if the text is the same forwards and backwards. i.e. "PooP" is a palindrome. This code simply takes the variable `text` and reverses it into `reversed_text`. In my example input `text` = `"PooP"`. If I reverse this into `reversed_text` = "PooP". Now I just test to see if they are euqal.

Comment: Note that you really only need to compare half of the strings. By the nature of palindromes the second half will be identical if you make it that far without a difference. You can take advantage of that and save yourself the effort of reversing in the first place. Compare each end. If they match move in one character on both ends and compare again Keep checking until you find a mismatch. If you reach the middle without a mismatch, you have a palindrome. No swapping and only N/2 compares.

Answer (score 1):

The code creates a string that is the reverse of the first one and compare if they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = text.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   reversed_text += text[i];
  }
```

Simply reverses input string. It iterates input string barwards and adds chars to `reversed_text` char by char. If `text` is `warchant`, then `reversed_text` would be `tnahcraw`.

More C++-ish way to do this is using `std::reverse`:

```
// don't forget to include this
#include <algorithm>

bool is_palindrome(std::string text){
  std::string reversed = text;
  std::reverse(reversed.begin(), reversed.end());
  ...
```

This function is not "most efficient code", but it will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

The code functions by inputting the reversed version of your input word and checks if the reversed version and the original version of the word are the same. As for the for loop, it works like this:

1. Get the position of the last character of the input word
2. Input that character into your reversed_text string
3. Continue as i decreases by 1, until the first character of the input word is inputted into the reversed_text string

Answer (score 0):

This line of code reads the word from reverse direction and concatenates with the variable reversed_text.

```
for (int i = text.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  reversed_text += text[i];
```

For example:

if text = "HELLO" then reversed_text="OLLEH"